# How do I make my program pass data to my array correctly? (Homework)

Tags: c++, c++11

I've set my array size to 20 (I set it to 19 assuming it's counting 0). I set my for loop to only run so long as gradeCount <= to gradeCounted yet it will keep running no matter how many times I enter data. If I enter 3 grades without pressing enter between each one, such as "23 23 23" it will return "Enter Grade" 3 times in a row, rather, for as many grades as I enter, separated by spaces. I don't understand why it's not passing data into the array and ending the for loop properly. I'm sure my code is an ugly mess, sorry.

Also, when entering code into stackoverflow, it said to indent the code 4 spaces to format? I couldn't initially indent the code with the code button and there was no {} button either. What am I missing? It was only after a notification to fix it that I was able to. Thanks for your time, I don't want to be a pain in the ass for you guys.

```
//This program asks user how many grades there are, inputs grades, and  displays median of said grades.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Variables
////////////////////const int limitGrades = 20; //Array "boxes"? //Ignore this //for now.
int gradeCounted; //Number of grades from user.
const int SIZE = 19;

//Array
float grades[19]; //Max grades that can be entered.

//Functions
void gradeTaker()
{
    cout << "You may input up to 20 grades. \n";
    cout << "First enter the number of grades you have: \n";
    cin >> gradeCounted;
    //requests how many grades there are and stores them in array
    for (int gradeCount = 0; gradeCount <= gradeCounted + 1; gradeCount++)
    {
        for (float &grade : grades)
        {
            cout << "Enter grade: \n";
            cin >> grade;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    gradeTaker();

    cout << "grades so far";
    for (int grade : grades)
        cout << grade << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your question to include the `#include ...`  and `using namespace std;` in the code block

Comment: You have a double `for` loop. Why? What does the inner loop accomplish?

Comment: FYI when initialising an array, the `[19]` is the number of elements to initialise, not the index. So if you try to do something like `myarray[19] = 0.0f;` you'll get a segfault

Comment: I used a nested for loop  because I wasn't sure how to have the ranged for loop parameter include into the first for loop. I didn't realize it could hold normal for loop parameters as well as ranged for loop parameters. I'm kinda in over my head. Forgot most of what I learned last semester.

Comment: You have two nested loops. The inner one iterates over all 19 values in the `grades` array. The outer loop iterates over whatever number of values were entered for the "number of grades". Therefore, if the number of grades was entered as 10, you will be obviously expected to enter 10*19 or 190 grades. What part of this do you have a question about?

Comment: In addition to that, the printing of `Enter grade: \n` over an over again is due to the fact that `cin` blocks until you hit the enter key, but it will treat what it got as a space separated list of values. So when you hit `23 23 23 ENTER` it unblocks, inserts 23, loops, prints string, inserts 23, loops, prints string. inserts 23, loops, prints string one more time, and then blocks.

Comment: So I'm guessing that I can't use a single ranged for loop for the purpose of this program that also takes normal for loop parameters? I just want my function to accept as many grades as the user enters as wanting to enter, to not allow the user to enter more than 20 grades if they enter more than 20 grades as "how many they want to enter" and I want it to exit the function when each of those grades have been entered and each grade added to the array. I doubt my code makes sense, but this is as far as my understanding goes. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of ranged for loops?

Comment: By design, a ranged for loop iterates over the entire collection.  If you want to iterate a subset of the array you need to either use the a for loop (as SCORP.io says in his answer) or you will have to add a counter and break... which is an argument for using an explicit for loop, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the array is separate from how you access it.  Accessing 20 values is the equivalent to accessing indices from 0 to 19.

```cpp
float grades[20];
for(size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++){ // print all values of grades
  std::cout << grades[i] << "\n";
}
```

Furthermore, your `for` loop in `gradeTaker` will ask you for a value for each index of `grades` a total of `gradeCounted + 2` times.  To fix this, only iterate over the indices that you're assigning a value to like so:

```
for (int gradeCount = 0; gradeCount < gradeCounted; gradeCount++){
  cout << "Enter grade: \n";
  cin >> grade[gradeCount];
}
```

Finally...  the `for` loop in your `main` function will iterate across the entire array which may include uninitialized values.  You should initialize the array or use a dynamic data structure like `std::vector` and just `push_back` the necessary values.

(P.s. highlight code in the text-block and press `CTRL+K` to indent.)

Comment: The for loop entering grades should check gradeCount against the size of the array too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this: "const int SIZE = 19;" even necessary to define my array size? My wife says her program needed it, but I don't understand why? Currently, just for the sake of collecting data for the array, using "float grades[20];" works fine. What exactly is the purpose of "const int SIZE = 19;"?

Comment: Jonathon K, when you say the for loop entering grades should check gradeCount against the array size, are you saying I need to include an if statement?

Comment: @SteveKovach - The size of an array needs to be [known at compile time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) (see #8).